# Getting checkmarx FLS_Create Error in apex

Tags: apex, apexrest, security-review, checkmarx

Checkmarx is giving me the FLS_Create error in the below code.

```
            cv.PathOnClient = docName;
            cv.VersionData = requestbody;
            cv.ContentLocation = 'S';
            cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
```

**The docName,requestbody are coming via rest parameters. so i am directly passing them in this function**

**Error displayed -:**
Method testDocwithAttachment at line 173 default\classes\InvAttachmentIngestionAPI.cls gets user input from element pathonclient. This input is later concatenated by the application directly into a string variable containing SQL commands, without being validated. This string is then used in method testDocwithAttachment to query the database cv, at line 173 of default\classes\InvAttachmentIngestionAPI.cls, without any additional filtering by the database. This could allow the user to tamper with the filter parameter.

**Method - :**

```
    global static boolean testDocwithAttachment(Blob requestBody, String invID, String docName) {
        try {
            
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            Id contentDocId;
            
            //  cv.Title = title;
            cv.PathOnClient = docName;
            cv.VersionData = requestbody;
            cv.ContentLocation = 'S';
            cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
            
            insert cv;
            
            System.debug(' id::' + cv.id);
            ContentVersion contversion = [SELECT Contentdocumentid FROM contentversion WHERE id = :cv.id];
            
            System.debug('contentdocument id::' + contversion.ContentDocumentId);
            contentDocId = contversion.ContentDocumentId;
            
            ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
            conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = contentDocId;
            conDocLink.ShareType = 'I';
            conDocLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
            conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = invID;
            insert conDocLink;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('error is::' + e);
            
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
   
}
```

I am calling this function via RestApi (Post) Class .
How to fix this problem.

Comment: It is trying to protect you from a SQL Injection attack, the data you are passing in is not validated. This means theoretically an attacker could give you something you do not expect as a parameter and steal information from the database. (I'm just translating the error for you). Which line specifically is `173`?

Comment: @Mattisdada These 4 line -: 
            `cv.PathOnClient = docName;`
            `cv.VersionData = requestbody;`
            `cv.ContentLocation = 'S';`
           `cv.IsMajorVersion = true;`

Comment: From what you show here, I'd say that this is a false positive response from Checkmarx. However, it may be that you haven't provided the full detail of the code and that the error relates to a usage not shown here.

Comment: @Phil
The testDocwithAttachment function accepts 3 parameters.So all of these parameters are inputted by a user in suppose in postman and then he calls the rest api class.My class then directly calls function 
`RestRequest req = RestContext.request;`  
`String docName = req.params.get('documentName');`
        `Blob requestbody = req.requestBody;`
Then just calling the function

Comment: What happens after that in the remainder of the REST flow, if anything?

Comment: @phil If function returns true i.e successfully inserting the requestbody(pdf) then 200 status code is returned other wise 400 statuscode.